# A function in Scheme to replace all occurrences of an element in a list with another element

Tags: scheme, racket

I am able to delete the element from a list, but I have no idea how to write a function in Scheme to replace all occurrences of an element in a list with another element.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761285/how-to-replace-an-item-by-another-in-a-list-in-drscheme-when-given-paramters-are

Answer (score 3):

A simple version might be designed like this:

```
(define (replace old-element new-element list)
  ; if the list is null, just return null
  ; else if the car of the list is equal to old-element
  ;    run replace on the rest of the list, and cons new-element onto it
  ; else
  ;    run replace on the rest of the list, and cons the car onto it)
```

(I left the details up to you, since you gotta learn by doing.)

Remember, in Scheme the most natural way to do things will usually be to assemble a new list piece-by-piece from your old list, not to try to make little changes one at a time  to your old list.

Note that you could also use `map` to do this much more concisely.

Comment: The syntax here is bad, it should be `(define (replace old new list) ...)`.  As for the actual implementation -- don't do this, use `map`.

Comment: I assumed that he is working from a guide or textbook that has gotten nowhere near `map` yet.

Comment: Any such book would have provided a similar kind of guiding, so it is either not needed because the book covers it, or because `map` is available.

Comment: Fair enough, that's probably true.