# Trying to replace all instances of an element in a list with a new element [Racket]

Tags: scheme, racket

As the title said, I'm trying to write a function that takes a list, a variable, and an element, then replaces all instances of the variable in the list with that element.

For example:

(substitute '(C or (D or D)) 'D #f) would return

'(C or (#f or #f))

Right now what I've got is:

```
(define (substitute lst rep new)
  (cond ((or (null? lst))
     lst)
    ((eq? (car lst) rep)
     (cons new (substitute (cdr lst) rep new)))
    (else
     (cons (car lst) (substitute (cdr lst) rep new)))))
```

Which doesn't check nested lists like my example, though it works fine when they aren't a part of the input.

And I'm having trouble with where to place recursion in order to do so - or would it be easier to flatten it all and then rebuild it after everything's been replaced in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using pattern matching via [`match`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html) -

```
(define (sub l rep new)
  (match l
    ((list (list a ...) b ...)    ; nested list
     (cons (sub a rep new)
           (sub b rep new)))
    ((list a b ...)               ; flat list
     (cons (if (eq? a rep) new a)
           (sub b rep new)))
    (_                            ; otherwise
     null)))
```

It works like this -

```
(sub '(a b c a b c a b c) 'a 'z)
;; '(z b c z b c z b c)

(sub '(a b c (a b c (a b c))) 'a 'z)
;; '(z b c (z b c (z b c)))

(sub '() 'a 'z)
; '()
```

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, your question looks similar to [How to replace an item by another in a list in DrScheme when given paramters are two items and a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761285/how-to-replace-an-item-by-another-in-a-list-in-drscheme-when-given-paramters-are). From my understanding, your question is slightly different because you also want to replace occurrences within nested lists.

In order to deal with nested lists, you must add a clause to check for the existence of a nested list, and replace all occurrences in that nested list by recursing down the nested list:

```
(define (subst l rep new)
  (cond ((null? l)
         '())
        ((list? (car l))  ; Check if it is a nested list.
         (cons (subst (car l) rep new)  ; Replace occurrences in the nested list.
               (subst (cdr l) rep new)))  ; Replace occurrences in the rest of the list.
        ((eq? (car l) rep)
         (cons new
               (subst (cdr l) rep new)))
        (else
          (cons (car l)
                (subst (cdr l) rep new)))))
```

Example use (borrowed from the answer given by user633183):

```
(subst '(a b c a b c a b c) 'a 'z)
;; '(z b c z b c z b c)

(subst '(a b c (a b c (a b c))) 'a 'z)
;; '(z b c (z b c (z b c)))

(subst '() 'a 'z)
; '()
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using map and recursion:

```
(define (subst lst rep new)
    (map (lambda (x)
            (if (list? x)                    
                (subst x rep new)
                (if (eq? rep x) new x))) lst))
```

the output:

```
(subst '(a b c (a b c (a b c))) 'a 'z)
; '(z b c (z b c (z b c)))
```